# Prevent class from being included in generated migration with Discriminator property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class that's being mapped into database table. Let's say this is my class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I am trying to create a child class that inherits Customer and adds few new fields like:

```
public class CustomerWithAttr : Customer
{
    public decimal Sum {get;set;}
}
```

The problem that arise is that when I now run Add-Migration I get:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "Sum", c => c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2));
    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
}
```

I haven't added anything to my Context class (like `DbSet<CustomerWithAttr>`). I just want to use my new child class (`CustomerWithAttr`) regardless of Migrations and I don't need database table for it. So how do I tell Entity Framework to ignore it and not generate unnecessary columns in migrations?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<CustomerWithAttr>();
}
```

Not the best solution from my perspective, but it works...